# Отсутствует запятая (ORA-00917)

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
  procedure InsertControlValuesToProtocol(p_VisualInspection in equipment_document_information.visual_inspection%type,
                                          p_Assaying in equipment_document_information.assaying%type) is
   begin

     insert into equipment_document_information
     (visual_inspection,
     assaying)
     values
     (p_VisualInspection,
     (p_Assaying)
   end;

  end InsertControlValuesToProtocol;
```

При попытке компиляции пакета, содержащего процедуру, выпадает ошибка ORA-00917: отсутствует запятая, ссылаясь на предпослеюнюю строку, содержащую просто end;. Где я мог ее потерять?

Comment: Внимательно посмотрите на запрос перед end. Во первых в последней строке явно лишняя открывающаяся скобка и во вторых после запроса нет точки с запятой. P.S. С такими ошибками могли бы сюда и не обращаться, нужно просто чуть чуть внимательности

Comment: И кстати ... а два end то зачем

Answer (score 3):

Вот здесь `(p_Assaying)` удалите скобку. Должно быть так: `p_Assaying)`